# client side javascript or server side

Tags: javascript, client-side, server-side

I have a report page that filters customers based on some criteria and displays their details on the browser. If the registration date of the customer is after a certain date say 1st January 2011, I need to highlight the date in a different color. I am wondering what is the best way to do this as there are around 800 records to display.

- if i check the date on the client side - javascript , i would be checking and comparing it with the certain date for each record which would slow down processing a lot
- if i run a scheduled script on the server side and set a flag in the database to indicate erroneous records which will set the color on display, how can i do this in a way which is scalable for other fields of the record??

UPDATE

Thanks for the great answers. So if I want to scale this to include all the fields of the record, would it be right to store a flag for each field in a separate table and then check the table to see which flags are set for each record and accordingly change the display??

Comment: The server should generate the markup (is it a table?  if so, then the `<td>` for the date) with a class value indicating the date status. Then you can use CSS to control appearance.  No need for JavaScript based on what you've described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case 2, when you mark your records on the server side, output can be done like that if you are using JSPs and the JSTL-Tag library:

**Warning: UNTESTED**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<c:forEach items="${customerList}" var="customer" varStatus="status">
    <c:if test="${status.first}">
        List of Customers:<br>
        <ul>
    </c:if>
            <li <c:if test="${customer.flag}">class="marked"</c:if>>
               <c:out value="${customer.name}"/>
            </li>
    <c:if test="${status.last}">
       </ul>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

If you want to mark entries depending on other records, then you have do adapt the script that sets the flag.

Comment: Thanks Christopher..I am using python and templates for the display. This is what I had in mind as well, however I am not sure of the right approach to scale it to other entries. I have updated the question to include my logic. Please take a look. Thanks

Comment: Generally you have to decide if you want to do filtering every time the data is displayed to be up to date. If you do so, it may be better to do it on the client to reduce the server load. With 800 entries that might work, at least when the client is no smartphone.

If up to date data isn't that important, then you can filter the data in a regular intervall (e.g. by calling a script nightly).

But it isn't yet completely clear to me, if you want only _one_ highlight type (one highlight color) or more than one. Because only when you want more than one, you need more than one flag.

Comment: ... and why not integrating those flag in your customer table? If you want only to highlight the field that is outdated you certainly need more than one flag.

To come back to the update of your question: If you store the flags in a separate table, then you should join that table with the customer table when delivering the customer list to the client. On the client you can highlight the fields based on the flags (e.g. with a c:if statement using JSTL tags and JPSs).

Comment: i want to store the flags in a different table for a cleaner design, so that the customer table just stores the customer details and then do a join to retrieve the results. There is a possibility that we will require to check other fields for erroneous data and display in different colors. Hence I am thinking of doing one flag per field.

Comment: as of now, I have implemented the checks on the server side and have a single flag for checking the registration date. if requirements change, i will adapt the table to include more flags.